# Fetch API information for stocks with ^ in the ticker name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch, alpha-vantage

I need some help calling the AlphaVantage stock market API. For the most part, it works nicely but when it comes to requesting data from stocks that have an `^` symbol in their ticker, something goes wrong.

I get the API response with this code:

```
var url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=^vvix&apikey=<KEY>", 
   response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url),
   json = JSON.parse(response);
Logger.log(json);
```

and get this error:

> Invalid argument: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&

The ticker symbol of the requested stock is `^vvix`. If I replace the symbol with like `vix` (another valid ticker) the code works. Thus, I assume the error has something to do with the `^` sign, but the `^` sign is part of the ticker symbol.

If i use

```
=IMPORTDATA("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=^vvix&apikey=K9D4PO855OG03KNM")
```

as a Google Sheets formula, the `^` is not a problem and the data is retrieved

Where is the difference?

Is `^` an invalid character in a JavaScript string?
Any idea whats the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caret ("^") is NOT a valid URL character and must be percent encoded if you follow the recommendations of the IETF. This is one of the "unsafe" characters defined in RFC1738

Use `%5E` in place of `^`.

More generally, wrap the symbol with:

```
encodeURI(symbol)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. `%5E` works. Is replacing ^ with %5E some kind of bad coding compared to using encode or is more or less equal ?

Comment: if you hardcode that is no problem - doing the wrapping just makes the whole exercise scalable to other characters - I'm not familiar with what other characters you may encounter in stock symbols